# Using javascript to adjust animation at certain times of day

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, time

I'm trying to use Javascript to alter how much a div moves, depending on the time of day.

Below is the code I am working with:

```
<style>

.whiterose-w{
animation-duration: 0.05s;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
position:absolute; 
}

/* BETWEEN MIDNIGHT AND MIDDAY */

.whiterose07 {
animation-name: shake2;
}

@keyframes shake2 {
    0% { transform: translate(0px); visibility: hidden; }
    1% { visibility: visible;}
    50% { transform: translate(0.7px);}
    100% { transform: translate(0px); }
}

/* BETWEEN MIDDAY AND MIDNIGHT */

.whiterose56 {
animation-name: shake5;
}

@keyframes shake5 {
    0% { transform: translate(0px); visibility: hidden; }
    1% { visibility: visible;}
    50% { transform: translate(5.6px);}
    100% { transform: translate(0px); }
}

</style>

<script>

// WHITEROSE SPEEDING UP TOWARDS MIDNIGHT !

var currentTime = new Date().getHours();

if (0 <= currentTime && currentTime < 12) {
  document.getElementsByClassName('whiterose-w').classList.add("whiterose07");
}
else if (12 <= currentTime && currentTime < 24) {
  document.getElementsByClassName('whiterose-w').classList.add("whiterose56");
}

</script>
```

So between midday and midnight the div should be moving 5.6px , and between midnight and midday should be moving 0.7px.. but where am I going wrong ?

Comment: Did you try removing from classList before adding?

Comment: Just tried this, but didn't seem to make a difference ! Should I be mixing ClassName and classList .. would it make any difference to be doing it with Id and classList instead ?